# Setting the state of a UiButton from a function in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have 7 Buttons to toggle the days in a week on and off. If, for example, the button for Sunday is pressed, an IBAction toggles the state automatically without any problems:

```
@IBAction func SoToggle(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.So.isSelected = !self.So.isSelected;
}
```

But when I try to set the state of that button from a function in the same class, I get an error saying:

> unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Here is the code used for setting "isSelected" to either true or false:

```
func setSo(state: Bool) {
    self.So.isSelected = state
}
```

I don't get why this is not working, because it's pretty much the same code.

EDIT:
The function is called by the TableViewController and the buttons are located in a custom TableViewCell. I included the whole code, just to make things clear.
TableViewController:

```
class TableViewSettings: UITableViewController{

let sections = ["weekdays", "start time"]

var CellDays:TableViewCellDays = TableViewCellDays()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.view.layer.cornerRadius = 7

    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10,left: 0,bottom: 0,right: 0)

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return self.sections[section]
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return sections.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return 1
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if(indexPath.section == 0) {
        return Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TableViewCellDays", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! TableViewCellDays
    } else {
        return Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TableViewCellPicker", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! TableViewCellPicker
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if(indexPath.section == 0) {
        return 80
    } else {
        return 150
    }
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 15
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 30
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let v: UIView = UIView()
    v.backgroundColor = .clear
    return v;
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TableViewCellHeader", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! TableViewCellHeader

    cell.mainLabel.text = sections[section]

    return cell
}

func setSettingsButtons(settings: [String]) {
//        if (settings[0] == "1") {
//            CellDays.Mo.isSelected = true
//        } else {CellDays.Mo.isSelected = false}
//        
//        if (settings[1] == "1") {
//            CellDays.Di.isSelected = true
//        } else {CellDays.Di.isSelected = false}
//        
//        if (settings[2] == "1") {
//            CellDays.Mi.isSelected = true
//        } else {CellDays.Mi.isSelected = false}
//        
//        if (settings[3] == "1") {
//            CellDays.Do.isSelected = true
//        } else {CellDays.Do.isSelected = false}
//        
//        if (settings[4] == "1") {
//            CellDays.Fr.isSelected = true
//        } else {CellDays.Fr.isSelected = false}
//        
//        if (settings[5] == "1") {
//            CellDays.Sa.isSelected = true
//        } else {CellDays.Sa.isSelected = false}
//        
//        if (settings[6] == "1") {
//            CellDays.So.isSelected = true
//        } else {CellDays.So.isSelected = false}

    CellDays.setSo(state: true)
}
```

TableViewCell:

```
class TableViewCellDays: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet var Mo: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var Di: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var Mi: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var Do: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var Fr: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var Sa: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var So: UIButton!

@IBOutlet var MoLeading: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet var DiLeading: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet var MiLeading: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet var DoLeading: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet var FrLeading: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet var SaLeading: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet var SoLeading: NSLayoutConstraint!



var offset: CGFloat = 10

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    // init Button states

    Mo.isSelected = false
    Di.isSelected = false
    Mi.isSelected = false
    Do.isSelected = false
    Fr.isSelected = false
    Sa.isSelected = false
    So.isSelected = false


    let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    let screenWidthCenter = screenWidth/2
    let frameWidth = Do.frame.width

    // Offset Settings depending on Device

    offset = screenWidth / 37

    print(offset)


    // X Coordinate Settings

    MoLeading.constant = screenWidthCenter - 3.5 * frameWidth - 3.75 * offset
    DiLeading.constant = screenWidthCenter - 2.5 * frameWidth - 2.75 * offset
    MiLeading.constant = screenWidthCenter - 1.5 * frameWidth - 1.75 * offset
    DoLeading.constant = screenWidthCenter - 0.5 * frameWidth - 0.75 * offset
    FrLeading.constant = screenWidthCenter + 0.5 * frameWidth + 0.25 * offset
    SaLeading.constant = screenWidthCenter + 1.5 * frameWidth + 1.25 * offset
    SoLeading.constant = screenWidthCenter + 2.5 * frameWidth + 2.25 * offset



}

@IBAction func MoToggle(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.Mo.isSelected = !self.Mo.isSelected;
}

@IBAction func DiToggle(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.Di.isSelected = !self.Di.isSelected;
}

@IBAction func MiToggle(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.Mi.isSelected = !self.Mi.isSelected;
}

@IBAction func DoToggle(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.Do.isSelected = !self.Do.isSelected;
}

@IBAction func FrToggle(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.Fr.isSelected = !self.Fr.isSelected;
}

@IBAction func SaToggle(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.Sa.isSelected = !self.Sa.isSelected;
}

@IBAction func SoToggle(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.So.isSelected = !self.So.isSelected;
}

func setSo(state: Bool) {
    self.Mo.isSelected = state
}
```

}

Comment: coud you check if all your IBOutlets are properly connected

Comment: Yes, that was the first thing I checked. Every button is connected properly.

Comment: could you put a breakpoint in the setSo and then check if all buttons are initiated and aren't nil ?

Comment: It seems that all your buttons are nil in the time you are sending the new state. It means that you are trying to set the new state too early (your controller or parent view that contains buttons is not loaded yet) or too late (your controller or parent view is deallocated, dismissed)
It will be better if you will show whole code

Comment: I see you've accepted an answer. Good! But why are you **not** using a `UISegmentedControl`? (I didn't go too far into the `UITableView` code, as I'm hopeful you aren't including 7 `UIButtons` in every cell. That's very poor UI.) A segmented control is *exactly* the thing you want when a user has (a) several choices they can change but (b) only one choice is allowed. Coding against that is quite easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to register the nib for table view to be able to use it.

Add in `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.tableView.register(UINib(nibName:"TableViewCellDays", bundle:nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "TableViewCellDays")
```

Replace your variable declaration as follows:

```
var CellDays:TableViewCellDays?
```

You will assign a value to it later in datasource methods.

Next in your `tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt` get this cell and assign the instance variable `CellDays` to it:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   if(indexPath.section == 0) {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCellDays") as! TableViewCellDays
        self.CellDays = cell
        return cell
   } else {
        return Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TableViewCellPicker", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! TableViewCellPicker
   }
}
```

**Only** after that you can call your `setSettingsButtons` method.

Comment: I get the error: "Argument labels do not match any available overloads."

Comment: @J.Doe Is your `TableViewCellDays` a view controller?

Comment: TableViewCellDays is a custom TableViewCell nib. The function is called by the ViewController.

Comment: @J.Doe So are you initializing the cell in `tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt`?

Comment: I just included the whole code to look at. The "setSettingsButtons" function is given a array with 7 bools to toggle the buttons. I just commented it out for testing purposes.

Comment: Thanks, now I don't get any error messages anymore, but it still doesn't call the function "setSo".

Comment: @J.Doe Which function you are talking about?